# Question 456314 re-open request

Tags: discussion, status-completed, reopen-request

I'm requesting to reopen this question:

[Why can't I copy the text from a PDF?](https://superuser.com/questions/456314/free-pdf-viewer-which-allows-copying-the-text)

There was a surprising solution found that nobody could have thought of.

Comment: Have you attempted to reword it beyond a product recommendation?

Comment: @random, what part do you want to be re-written? title? maybe give a suggestion?

Comment: As it stands, the whole thing could do

Comment: @random - I have edited the question and voted to reopen. What do you think?

Comment: @Nifle, i think i can rewrite question better... that is harder to google i think

Comment: @Rookie - Go ahead.

Comment: @Rookie: Please post your solution as an answer, you can find the removed last paragraph in http://superuser.com/revisions/57968bec-c854-4b67-8170-ffda4567ab67/view-source

Comment: @TomWijsman, okay... i thought to give the bonus points to the guy who actually found this, but as he didnt reply, i guess i should answer it myself.

Answer (score 1):

I have edited the question and voted to reopen.
If it gets reopened, make your **Edit** into to a proper answer. Then you can accept it after a while (a day or so I forget)